# How to select a random image from the array list?

Tags: angular6

I have an array of images

```
 selectImages = ['https://bootdey.com/img/Content/user_1.jpg', 'https://bootdey.com/img/Content/user_2.jpg', 'https://bootdey.com/img/Content/user_3.jpg'];
```

I need to show a random image in my html. I have following function to select the image:

```
pickImage = function () {
    var myImage = this.selectImages[Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)];
    return myImage;
};
```

Now in html i did {{pickImage}}. But I am getting error:

```
ERROR Error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'src: https://bootdey.com/img/Content/user_3.jpg'. Current value: 'src: https://bootdey.com/img/Content/user_2.jpg'.
```

Comment: since it is a function you should call it like `{{pickImage()}}`
and since you are not changing the image after first pick - you can just run that code in component constructor and assign the result to a field like `randomImage: string`

Answer (score 1):

```
myImage : 'loadingImage.jpeg';

ngAfterViewInit()
{
    this.pickImagefun();
} 

pickImagefun = function () {
    this.myImage = this.selectImages[Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)];

};
```

now int html you can use  {{myImage }}.

You have to call your function in ngAfterViewInit.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to put it one of the lifecycle hooks of angular. Either 
       ngAfterContentChecked() - Respond after Angular checks the content projected into 
       the directive/component.
Or 
       ngAfterViewChecked() - Respond after Angular checks the component's views and child 
       views / the view that a directive is in.